# $.get not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I used this method to load page...

```
function remoteCall(sUrl, sQueryStr, sCalledBy)
{
    var str = " { ";

        $.post(sUrl,sQueryStr, function(data){
            sResponse[sCalledBy] = data;  //alert(data);
            eval(" "+sCalledBy+"()");
        });
}
```

but when I changed `$.post` to `$.get` it doesn't work. Actually I need to change this because I am loading this page from a remote page.

Answer (score 3):

> i need to change this bcoz i am
>   loading this page from remote page....

You need to have a look at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> In computing, the same origin policy
>   is an important security concept for a
>   number of browser-side programming
>   languages, such as JavaScript. The
>   policy permits scripts running on
>   pages originating from the same site
>   to access each other's methods and
>   properties with no specific
>   restrictions, but prevents access to
>   most methods and properties across
>   pages on different sites.

For you to be able to get data, it has to be:

**Same protocol and host**

You need to implement [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) to workaround it.